# How do i open this menu

Tags: edit-mode

so i closed the menu on the right of the screen, the left is opened with "T" is there a shortcut to open the right one? And no not the one opened with "N".
[image]
[See here :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRwqw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your could go to File >> Load Factory Settings

Or you could do the following:
[image]

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

No keyboard shortcut, but it will come back if you click that tiny + in the top right.

Alternatively, save your file. Go to File -> New to open an entirely new file with (what should be) the correct UI.

Then go to File -> Open and open your blend file, but un-tick "Load UI" in the bottom left before you click open.

Blender loads the UI layout with the file. If you tell it not to by un-ticking that box, it keeps whatever UI you just had.